# Sql Server Mostrar u ocultar columna según condición

Tags: sql, sql-server, condiciones, stored-procedure

Tengo una pregunta super puntual; se trata de un sp de personas usado para personas y personas hijo mayor.

Necesito mostrar u ocultar un par de columnas dependendiendo la condición de una variable:

```
Declare @ListaHijoMayor bit
Set @ListaHijoMayor=0
--Set @ListaHijoMayor=1
Select      p.dni,
            case when @ListaHijoMayor=1 then "ph.dniPadre as DNI del Padre",
                                        else "''"
            end
            case when @ListaHijoMayor=1 then "ph.nombrePadre as Nombre del Padre",
                                        else "''"
            end
            p.Nombres,
            p.Apellidos,
            p.Direccion
from persona p
left join PadresPersonas ph on p.dni=ph.dniHijoMayor
```

La idea condicionar el mostrar u ocultar el dni y nombre del padre, en caso que la variable @ListaHijoMayor venga en cero lo que significa que el listado es de personas.

Usando Case When entre comillas deje la condición que debiese aplicar.

No quiero usar exec @VarSqlDelSelect pues tengo un sp con 1000 lineas y condiciones las que al volver string, podría pasar cualquier cosa.

Gracias por vuestra ayuda.

Comment: debe desaparecer la columna del resultado o debe aparecer la columna, pero con datos vacíos?

Comment: No olvides incluir en las etiquetas el motor con el que trabajas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se me ocurre que tienes básicamente 3 opciones para resolver este problema:

- La primera opción es *incluir* siempre TODAS las columnas, pero en el caso que no deba y excluir la información en uno de los casos (devolver NULL para ellas). Esto implica hacer alguna programación especial en el programa desde donde se está ejecutando la consulta, por ejemplo para ocultar la columna al usuario en una grilla, una página web o un reporte impreso, o para no incluirla en una respuesta de un API, por ejemplo:

  ```
  declare @idTabla1 bigint = 1;
  declare @incluirColumnaCondicional bit;
  set @incluirColumnaCondicional = 0;

  select   tabla1.columna1
         , tabla1.columna2
         , tabla2.columna3
         , case when @incluirColumnaCondicional then tabla3.ColumnaCondicional end as ColumnaCondicional
         , tabla4.Columna5
    from tabla1
         inner join tabla2 on tabla2.idTabla2 = tabla1.idTabla2
         inner join tabla3 on tabla3.idTabla3 = tabla2.idTabla3
         inner join tabla4 on tabla4.idTabla4 = tabla4.idTabla4
   where tabla1 = @idTabla1
  ```

  Esta solución me gusta, porque es fácil de programar y de mantener.
- La siguiente, en grado de complejidad es generar una cadena con la sentencia de la consulta que quieres ejecutar y hacerlo de manera dinámica. Sé que has dicho en tu pregunta que no quieres hacer esto, pero no puedo dejar de mencionarla, ya que, en mi opinión, es una alternativa viable y mejor que la tercera. Si tienes una consulta de 1000 líneas, bueno, lo siento, será un par de horas pesadas, pero si eres ordenado, la conversión podrá ser tediosa, pero es posible sin que *pase cualquier cosa*.

  La idea básica es:

  ```
    declare @idTabla1 bigint = 1;
    declare @incluirColumnaCondicional bit;
    set @incluirColumnaCondicional = 0;

    declare @sql nvarchar(max);
            set @sql = '
    select   tabla1.columna1
           , tabla1.columna2
           , tabla2.columna3' 
    + case when @incluirColumnaCondicional = 1 then '
           , tabla3.ColumnaCondicional'
      else '' 
      end
    + '
           , tabla4.Columna5
      from tabla1
           inner join tabla2 on tabla2.idTabla2 = tabla1.idTabla2
           inner join tabla3 on tabla3.idTabla3 = tabla2.idTabla3
           inner join tabla4 on tabla4.idTabla4 = tabla4.idTabla4
     where tabla1 = @idTabla1
    ';

    print @sql;
    sp_executesql(@sql, '@idTabla1 bigint', @idTabla1 = @idTabla1);
  ```
- Mi última opción es tener dos *consultas* dentro de tu procedimiento. Estas consultas son *idénticas*, excepto por la columna que se incluye en una y se excluye en otra. En base a la condición se ejecutar una u otra

  Esto es propicio a errores a la hora de darle mantenimiento al sistema, pues se puede perder la sincronía entre una consulta y la otra:

  ```
    declare @idTabla1 bigint = 1;
    declare @incluirColumnaCondicional bit;
    set @incluirColumnaCondicional = 0;

    if @incluirColumnaConcicional = 0 
      select   tabla1.columna1
             , tabla1.columna2
             , tabla2.columna3
             , tabla4.Columna5
        from tabla1
             inner join tabla2 on tabla2.idTabla2 = tabla1.idTabla2
             inner join tabla3 on tabla3.idTabla3 = tabla2.idTabla3
             inner join tabla4 on tabla4.idTabla4 = tabla4.idTabla4
       where tabla1 = @idTabla1
    else
      select   tabla1.columna1
             , tabla1.columna2
             , tabla2.columna3
             , tabla3.ColumnaCondicional
             , tabla4.Columna5
        from tabla1
             inner join tabla2 on tabla2.idTabla2 = tabla1.idTabla2
             inner join tabla3 on tabla3.idTabla3 = tabla2.idTabla3
             inner join tabla4 on tabla4.idTabla4 = tabla4.idTabla4
       where tabla1 = @idTabla1
  ```